# 3D Array de-allocation gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making use of a three dimensional array. I am declaring it like this:

```
int (*DoubleStride_StateTable)[255][255] = new int[StateTable_length][255][255];
```

and I deallocate the 3D array  like this:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 255 ; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < 255 ; j++ )
    {
        cout << i << " " << j << endl;
        delete[] DoubleStride_StateTable[i][j] ;
    }
    delete[] DoubleStride_StateTable[i] ;
}
delete[] DoubleStride_StateTable;
```

The loop runs just two times i.e

```
i=0 j=0
i=0 j=1
```

and afterwards a segmentation faults occurs

Am I doing correct deallocation? Why is this error occurring ?

Comment: Not a C++ expert here, but I think you just want `delete[] DoubleStride_StateTable`.

Comment: How many `new`-s are there ? Now how many `delete`-s are there ?

Comment: @user2357112 you give yourself less credit than you deserve. Both the observation and your syntax are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're freeing things you shouldn't free yourself. (Or more specific: you're trying to free parts of your allocated memory multiple times.)

Basic rule of thumb: If you request memory using `new` once, then you must only use `delete` once as well. The same is true for arrays: If you're using `new[]` once, you must only use `delete[]` once as well.

You'll only need the line

```
delete[] DoubleStride_StateTable;
```

to free all memory that has been reserved in your declaration.

Iterating over all elements/levels and freeing elements the way you did is only necessary when you're creating your 3D array the same way (creating an array of pointers, then iterating over it and assigning another level).